# Spark: how to read CompactBuffer from an objectFile?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, object-files, sequencefile

I am reading the following structure from an object file:

```
(String, CompactBuffer(person1, person2, person3 ...) )
```

If I tried to read like this:

```
val input = sc.objectFile[(String, ListBuffer[Person])]("inputFile.txt")

val myData = input.map { t =>
  val myList = t._2
  for (p <- myList) {
    println(p.toString())
  }
  t
}
```

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
```

---

However, I can NOT use CompactBuffer when read the objectFile either:

```
val input = sc.objectFile[(String, CompactBuffer[Person])]("inputFile.txt")
```

Eclipse would just tell me:

```
class CompactBuffer in package collection cannot be accessed in package 
 org.apache.spark.util.collection
```

---

So how do I read such CompactBuffer from an objectFile? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/CompactBuffer.scala we can see that `CompactBuffer` is a sub-class of Seq, so try `val input = sc.objectFile[(String, Seq[Person])]("inputFile.txt")`